# PHP file into an HTML file

Tags: php, html, embed

So I want to create a rather large text area
for different price tags and by the extent of the code in the html file
I thought that proceeding with an embedded PHP with this information would
decrease the amount of code and also simplify editing for information purposes

what I want to know is how I can embed this sort of code which is in HTML now
with PHP into my Index.html

so my code which consist of a very large text is:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2> Products</h2>
     <p> 
     </p>

     <h2> Prices </h2>
     <p>.</p>

<h2> Delivery </h2>

<p>  </p>

<h2>  </h2>
<p>.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I want this to be in a PHP file and then embedded into my 
Index file:

```
     <div class="textInfo">
     <h1> Sales </h1>
     <?php include 'Test.php'; ?>

     <div class="text">

     </div>    

</div>
```

and I really like to know how you proceed with this
cause I cant seem to get it working.

Comment: Just rename the file to `index.php`. A `.php` is HTML _plus_ PHP. I'm not sure if that's what you're asking?....

Comment: I think he understands this, as he's using php include inside of html

Comment: Well he stated this **now with PHP into my Index.html**. But PHP can't be placed into a `.html` @wavemode

Comment: PHP can be placed in `.html`, but for it he should reconfigure `.htaccess`.  Info: http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm